# JQuery tab not showing properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I tried the following in order to create Jquery tabs:

```
    <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <p>Tab 1 content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <p>Tab 2 content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
     <p>Tab 3 content</p>
    </div>
    </div>  

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#tabs").tabs();

    });
    </script>
```

What I show is the following:

```
First
Second
Third
```

Tab 1 content

Tab 2 content

Tab 3 content

Am I missing the necessary jquery library? Which one should I be using?

Comment: Did you remember to include the jQuery UI library and CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you included jQuery UI css and js file? You can add it from CDN like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: This is more of a comment then an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to include the jQuery UI css file.**

Applying `tabs()` will set classes such as: `ui-tabs-hide`

But without the jQuery UI CSS file, your browser won't know to hide this element.

Using Google Chrome, Inspect element and you'll see the classes added to the elements. I've provided a jsfiddle as an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/TjNAw/

You can download and customise your jQuery UI CSS file from the theme roller here:

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/